# What does average of log-transformed variable mean?

Tags: regression, mean

In my bivariate regression model, I log-transformed the dependent variable. and the mean is now 2.77. and I got -0.186 for coefficient.

Could anyone tell me the interpretation of 2.77 here? and how can it compare with -0.186?

Comment: What is the independent variable? It is continuous, binary, etc.? And when you say the "mean" is 2.77, is that the intercept you're referring to?

Comment: the equation I got is Y=4.107-0.186X. Both x and y is continuous. but the mean of the log transformed data is 2.77.  what does 2.77 mean in this case?

Answer (score 3):

Before going into the details, the mean of a log-transformed variable is indeed the mean of the log-transformed variable. However, its exponential form has a special identity called [geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean). This explanation will tap into this idea.

Let's assume your independent variable is continuous. Given

$$\ln(y) = 4.107 - 0.186x $$

for one unit increase in $x$, we then have:

$$\ln(y') = 4.107 - 0.186(x+1)$$

Solving the two equations, we have:

$$\ln(y') - \ln(y) = -0.186$$

Because $\ln(A) - \ln(B) = \ln(A/B)$:

$$\ln(y'/y) = -0.186$$

Now, let's take away the log, but doing so means $y'/y$ will not be interpreted as a ratio of two arithmetic means, but rather a ratio of two geometric means.

$$y'/y = 0.8303$$

So, the interpretation is then: corresponding to one unit increase in $x$, the geometric mean changes by a factor of 0.8303, a 17% decrease.

<><><><><><><><><><>

Now, for the mean: $\exp(2.77) = e^{2.77}$ is 15.96, and this is the geometric mean of $y$.

<><><><><><><><><><>

R code for reference:

```
set.seed(2208)
x <- sample(seq(1:10), 5, replace=T)
x

# This is geometric mean
(6*4*6*4*9)^(1/5)

# Mean of log(x)
mean(log(x))
# Exponent is the geometric mean
exp(mean(log(x)))
```

Output:

```
> set.seed(2208)
> x <- sample(seq(1:10), 5, replace=T)
> x
[1] 6 4 6 4 9
> 
> # This is geometric mean
> (6*4*6*4*9)^(1/5)
[1] 5.532647
> 
> # Mean of log(x)
> mean(log(x))
[1] 1.710666
> # Exponent is the geometric mean
> exp(mean(log(x)))
[1] 5.532647
```

Comment: thanks. that is very helpful. for 3 unit increase in X, do I just subtract ln(y′)=4.107−0.186(x+3) by the ln(y)=4.107−0.186x?

Comment: Yes, essentially the factorial change would be $exp^{-0.186 \times 3}$, which is 0.572, a 42.8% decrease. You can also figure out the one unit change (which is 0.8303), and power this up: $0.8303^3$.

Comment: another thing I am confused with is that can I compare 0.8303 (geometric mean changes by a factor of 0.8303) with the 2.77 (mean of logged dependent variable) to show the substantive magnitude of the change?

Comment: Yes and no, "substantive" or not would depend on what your original value is because it's not absolute change, but a factorial change. For instance, is 50% change "substantive"? Losing 25 cents out of 50 cents and losing 50 millions out of 100 millions are of two different scales. So, you may need to set up some possible scenario (aka, use the median case as a sample case), compute the change, and then interpret if that change is "substantive."

Comment: sorry, i don't quite get how to find out whether the effect is substantive? can you explain more please?

Comment: Something just dropped by 17%, is it substantive? The answer is it depends on what is "substantive" and what the variables are. The follow up question is mixing statistical significance with practical importance and I cannot answer given no knowledge in your analysis. What I suggest is you can show the change by using a sample case, and i) decide if the change is substantive yourself, and ii) let other people who read your analysis to decide.

Comment: For instance, if the median of $y$ is 230, then a unit increase in $x$ would be associated with about 40 unit drop. Interpret yourself if it's substantive.

Comment: thanks. but in my case, I have log-linear model, which the interpretation is in terms of percentage change. so what do I compare it with?  eg. will it make sense if I compare 0.8303 to  exp(2.77)=15.96? in other word, are these two number comparable?

Comment: If x increases by one, then 15.96 will become (15.96 * 0.8303). If you consider that "comparing." Just notice that what usually work in linear regression may not work very well in log-linear. You're asking people to perceive a multiplicative scale as additive, I wouldn't go there.

Comment: I have to thank you Penguin_Knight. it has been veeerrryyy helpful.